# How do I fix a dent on my frame?

Tags: frames, damage, corrosion

I suspect that something has pierced my frame. At any rate, I have a dent in my bike frame. I would like to avoid the possibility of corrosion, with minimium cosmetic trade off. So, how do I go about fixing the dent?

**EDIT**

I have since noticed that nothing has pierced my frame. However, there is corrosion.

Here is the frame spec:

Frame Material: Steel

Frame Size: 17-18

Frame: Voodoo Black Magic butted thin wall heat treated Cro-mo frame

[image: View 2]
[image: View 3]
[image: View 4]
[image: View 5]
[image: View 6]
[image: View 7]

Comment: Could you provide a photo of the problematic spot?

Comment: What's your frame made from? Steel has problems with corrosion, aluminum and carbon not so much.

Comment: Failing a photo, a description of where the problem is would also help.

Comment: Thanks chaps, I have edited and uploaded a few shots of the frame damage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your frame isn't pierced through, I wouldn't bother with it much.

Apply some paint of correct type (I'm no expert, consult your local home improvement/paint shop) to stop further corrosion. You might want to remove the existing rust with a fine sandpaper before putting the paint on (again, refer to the manual of the paint or consult the shop).

I think there are even some special paints for fixing car finishes available in car shops but that might be a little too expensive.

The important thing is to prevent direct contact between the bare steel and water / air humidity if you don't want the rusting to progress.

---

EDIT: A cheap solution might even be a waterproof and airtight adhesive tape.

Comment: Apparently it's also important to remove existing rust, before you seal it.

Comment: For a small area nail polish is often enough, but you really should use a metal primer then suitable paint. You can get self-priming paint for metal (ie, not self-priming paint for wood), but usually only in 250ml tins. Spraypaint is the other easy option, but again only in large quantities. Ideally find someone who has some and give them a couple of bucks for the wee patch you need.

Comment: Maybe even some smaller car workshop would help out for a few bucks on the side.

Comment: @Moz: I wonder if I can buy Rockstar Red nail polish, you entrepreneur

Comment: There are some rust-converters on the market. I would brush the already-nonpainted and already-rusted parts of the bent with some steel fabric or steel brush, then apply the rust-converter, then brush again, and then use nailpolish.